# Derivative of $\phi(x)=\begin{cases} e^{-\frac{1}{1-x^2}}, & x\in (-1,1)\\ 0, &x \not \in (-1,1)\end{cases}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function

Let the function:
\begin{equation}
\phi(x)=\begin{cases} e^{-\frac{1}{1-x^2}}, & x\in (-1,1)\\ 0, &x \not \in (-1,1)\end{cases}
\end{equation}
How can I show that $\phi(x)$ is differentiable and that $\phi'(\pm1)=0$?

**My approach**

One similar problem that I have read is to prove that for the function $\alpha(x)=e^{-1/x}$ which considers the power series for the exponential function from which it holds that $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $e^y\geq \frac{y^n}{n!}, \forall y \geq 0$. Taking that into account, one can show that for the function $\alpha(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$ it holds:
\begin{equation}
\alpha(x)=\frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{x}}} \leq \frac{n!}{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^n}=n!x^n
\end{equation}
which tells us that $\alpha(x)$ is differentiable at $0$ with $\alpha'(0)=0$.

1. Why is this true?
2. How can I apply this to my current problem?

I also tried to apply the definition of the derivative but it seems to be quite a complicated limit to solve.

Thank you!

Comment: In the second inequality you assume $x>0$, right?

Comment: Yeap that is right. That is actually the reason why I am not sure that I can apply that example to my current problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need exact formulas the derivatives of $\phi.$ In $(-1,1),$ every derivative of $\phi$ has the form $$e^{-1/(1-x^2)}p(x)(1-x^2)^{-m}$$ for some $m\in \{0,1,\dots \},$ where $p$ is a polynomial. Functions of this type $\to 0$ at $\pm 1$ from within $(-1,1).$ This implies $\phi^{(k)}(x) = 0, |x|\ge 1,$ for all $k,$ proving $\phi \in C^\infty(\mathbb {R}).$

Comment: Alright, this exactly what I want to prove! The second part of this problem states to prove that $\phi \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$. Can you guide me throught this proof? You state that functions of this type must $\to 0$ at $\pm 1$. How can I prove that? It took a lot of paper but still I am not able to.

Comment: Well, $p$ is bounded, so forget about it. The rest is just exponential decay vs. polynomial growth. Try setting $u = -1/(1-x^2).$  Then $u\to - \infty$ as $x \to \pm 1.$

Comment: Thank you! I just went through the process and it is simple the way you put it! Sometimes, all it takes is a different angle of view. I know it is not proper to ask it here but since you seem to deal well with these functions, do you know any possible way to solve the integral: $\int _{-1}^{1}xe^{\frac{1}{1-x^2}}$? Thank you again!

Comment: It's odd so the integral is $0.$

Comment: One last question.. Why is $p$ bounded? How can I see that? Thank you once again!

Comment: It's a polynomial, hence is bounded on any bounded interval.